# Почему метод splice удаляет значение из массива и из копии этого массива

Tags: javascript

```js
// Пусть у меня один массив.
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

// Я решаю скопировать этот массив во второй:
var array2 = [];
var array2 = array1;

// Удаляю любой элемент(в данном случае с индексом 0) из второго массива:
array2.splice(0, 1)

// В итоге:
console.log(array1); // ["b", "c", "d"]
console.log(array2); // ["b", "c", "d"]`
```

То есть каким-то образом метод `.splice()` удаляет элементы из обоих массивов. Почему?

Comment: Потому что вы скопировали не массив, а ссылку на один и тот же массив

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Присвоив ссылку на массив в еще одну переменную, Вы не создали новый массив, Вы сделали именно то , что описано выше. Обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же массив.

Таким образом `splice` модифицирует единственный массив, которым Вы оперируете.

Скопируйте массив хотя бы так:

```
var array2 = [...array1];
```

или так:

```
var array2 = array1.slice(0);
```